vb.net display current week database records
I found some other reference here in internet and tried this code so far, but seems not to work. Can someone help rearrange or modify my code for displaying record current week.
Sub loadCheck()
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblchecklist where check_corporate='" & mainfrm.lbl_server.Text & "' and select yearweek('2024-01-01 00:00:00'), yearweek(curdate())", conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds, "tblchecklist")
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = (ds.Tables("tblchecklist"))
End Sub

I get this error:

Exception User-Unhandled MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select yearweek('2024-01-01 00:00:00'), yearweek(curdate())' at line 1


Arg... this is crazy-vulnerable to SQL injection. DO NOT USE STRING CONCATENTATION LIKE THAT FOR SQL!

Also, how do you expect to get help if you don't tell us what went wrong beyond just "seems not to work"?

Exception User-Undhandle
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select yearweek('2024-01-01 00:00:00'), yearweek(curdate())' at line 1'

Thats what it prompts after running

Okay. Now edit the question to include that info inline.

And by string concatentation, what do you mean by that? Sorry if im kinda slow with this, im still learning on database slowly

Add a tag for the dbms you're using. (Date/time functionality is often vendor specific, e.g. yearweek()...)

Working on an answer that will demonstrate how to avoid the string concatenation problem.

It should be obvious if you have done any research into SQL that you should not have the SELECT keyword in that query twice. There isn't much that is simpler than the basic structure of a query in SQL.

To understand why using strings that way is bad, picture what would happen if I typed '; DROP TABLE tblchecklist; -- into that text box (Don't do it on a production system!). You expect to run one command, but you actually submit two commands and a comment, and the second command is entirely defined by me.

The problem is this section of the sql:
and select yearweek('2024-01-01 00:00:00'), yearweek(curdate())

Unfortunately, there's not enough information in the question to fix this for you, because it seems like this should target a specific column in the table and we are not given the names of any of those columns.
But in order to provide an answer, I'll assume there's a column named check_date we should use, and the correct expression looks more like this:
and yearweek(check_date) = yearweek(curdate())

But this is still sub-optimal. The SQL will be more efficient if you compute start and end dates of the desired range, and supply those as query parameters using a half-open range with an exclusive upper boundary targeting the day after the range ends
and check_date >= @StartDate and check_date < @EndDate

This will perform MUCH better, because the original had to calculate the yearweek for every row in the table, while this avoids that calculation entirely, and because this option still works with indexes where the original would not use indexes at all, which cuts to the core of database performance.
You also need to use parameterized queries. THIS IS A BIG DEAL! and failing to make this fix (because the code really is broken without it, even if it seems to work in testing) will leave your app open to trivial hacks and even accidental user errors.
Because of ADO.Net connection pooling, you also should NOT try to re-use the same connection object everywhere. It really is better to allocate a new connection for most queries. You can make this easier by moving ALL your DB code to a common module.
Put it all together like this:
Public Module DB
    Private connectionString As String = " your connection string here "

    Public Function ChecksThisWeek(Server As String) As DataTable
        ' First day of the current week
        Dim StartDate As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-Weekday(DateTime.Today, FirstDayOfWeek.System) + 1)
        Dim EndDate As DateTime = StartDate.AddDays(7)

        Dim result As New DataTable()
        Dim SQL As String = "
SELECT * 
FROM tblchecklist 
WHERE check_corporate= @Server
    AND check_date >= @StartDate AND check_date < @EndDate"
      
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(connectionString), _
              cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, con), _
              da  As New MySqlDataAdapater(cmd)

              ' These values are NEVER replaced directly in the SQL string
              ' Instead, they are submitted to the DB server in a separate data block
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Server", Server)
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate)
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", EndDate)
              da.Fill(result)
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function

    ' Other places where you access the DB should each get their own methods in this module
    ' If the app gets more complex and the module grows big enough
    ' you can then move it to it's own class library project,
    ' with separate types for each logical area of the application

End Module

' ...

Sub loadCheck()
    Try
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = DB.ChecksThisWeek(mainfrm.lbl_server.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try 
End Sub

Note I've also seen environment that give the connection string special handling, because it can have sensitive keys, and they don't want them accidentally ending up in source control. In that situation,  you may need to consider using dependency injection to create the connection objects... but you still need new connection objects for each query.

just edited my former code with this line and yearweek(check_date) = yearweek(curdate()) and now perfectly works. Thank you so much

by the way, just wanted to clarify something. With yearweek(check_date). What does this mean? Is it a date starting Jan. 1, 2024? or my earliest check_date records which is 04/01/24?

@NnekLecxe it gets the yearweek() for the values in the check_date column. But as per the 4th paragraph, this is WAAAY SLOWER. It's not close. You should use the code further down.

lastly, tried to work with your long code with some modifications that suits for my preference with parameters. sample code. But this one doesn't seem to produce same results with my former code.

@NnekLecxe Creating a new connection for each query is NOT JUST  A PREFERENCE.    The connection you use in code is a thin wrapper around a much more expensive connection managed by a pool. When you keep the same object prevent the pool from doing it's job properly and makes the app slower and use more memory, not less. You also force yourself to serialize database access that might otherwise be able to happen in parallel. And as for the code at the image link above: in the event of an error it holds the connection open until the messagebox is cleared, which could be NEVER.

[cont] The one thing we could do is add try/catch support to the calling code, which I will do in a moment. But as for the different result: make sure the start and end dates match what you expect for the start and end of the week. For example, it's possible there's a mismatch where one system uses Monday instead of Sunday as the first day of the week.

edited: i've tried your above code, and seems to be working smoothly now, thank you so much!

Lets say I want to start my week from Monday to Saturday, code should be Dim EndDate As DateTime = StartDate.AddDays(6) ? and Dim StartDate As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-Weekday(DateTime.Today, FirstDayOfWeek.System) + 1)

If the week starts on Monday and ends on Saturday, such that no Sunday data is ever included, then AddDays(6) will be correct. But remember: you want an exclusive boundary on the upper end of the range for the day after. This is because too many systems eventually end up needing full time stamps, where you need to be able to account for times later on in the day on the last day of the range, and there are mismatches between how the client language like C# or VB handles the last moment of the day vs how the DB handles the last moment of the day, so using 11:59:59 PM is wrong.

As for StartDate, that uses the first day of the week as defined in the culture settings on your local system. You might prefer to instead require a different day. You can do this easily enough by mapping days of the week to integer values for various days, checking the current day of the week, and resolving to the map to get your offset for AddDays() (Hint: while you could use a dictionary for this, existing DayOfWeek enum already gives you integer values you can use as a starting point)
